# nginx proxy_pass 404 error, don't understand why

Tags: nginx

I am trying to pass off all calls to /api to my webservice but I keep getting 404s with the following config. Calls to / return index.html as expected. Does anyone know why?

```
upstream backend{
    server localhost:8080;
}

 server {

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location / {
        root /html/dir;
    }
}
```

## More info here

```
adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost/api/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost:8080/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:20 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"user":["false"],"emailAddress":["false"]}
```

Comment: Is the location available at the backend server?

Comment: yeah calls directly to the webservice on 8080 are working as expected

Comment: is it nginx or the webservice that responds with 404?

Comment: I made edits to the question for more info on that

Answer (score 184, accepted):

This

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Needs to be this

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
}
```

Comment: Seems to fix the issue, but an explanation of what difference this makes would be nice.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me. In fact it makes it worse and gives me a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in chrome.

Comment: 0xAffe - mind the both slashes at the and of the path and proxy_pass url. The too many redirects sometimes happen if you missed one of the slashes

Comment: oh wow. i had it working without the trailing slash for other backends, but this one needed it for some reason.

Comment: Nginx config is really confusing. So how this slash in the end matters?

Comment: That does not fix it.

Comment: Hi should this be added in default or nginx.conf ?

Comment: @user1338062 the explanation of what difference this makes is in one of the below answers. It has to do with whether nginx alters the path or not.

Comment: If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended.

Comment: It is strange, i've been two hours breaking my head, to finally find that unlike apache, nginx requires the trailing slash to work.

Answer (score 78):

Just want to remind others that the slash(backend*/*) after your proxy_pass url is very important!

if the config is

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

and you visit `http://abc.xyz/api/endpoint`, you would be directed to `http://backend/api/endpoint`;

if the config is

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
}
```

and you visit `http://abc.xyz/api/endpoint`, you would be directed to
`http://backend/endpoint`.

That's the difference.

For more, refer to: [Nginx reverse proxy return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609509/nginx-reverse-proxy-return-404?rq=1)

Comment: Wow. This issue just slash-ed my day.

Comment: OMG, I spent so long debug this. Not one tutorial and example I read explained this issue...

Answer (score 15):

By some reason proxy_pass in Nginx cuts header "Host" before passing to upstream, and request catches by default server, and even proxy_header_pass doesn't helps, so I've to explicitly set it:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to troubleshoot step by step to identify which point that possibly cause the issue. Here are some possible mistakes:

#### The Nginx configuration changed but Nginx did not reload it

This might be occur when you override the `nginx.conf` file but didn't trigger nginx to reload the config. Might frequently occur to docker user.
To reload the nginx configs, while in the Nginx host, execute command: `nginx -s reload`
With docker: `docker exec <container_name> nginx -s reload`
Ref: [Controlling NGINX Processes at Runtime](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/)

#### The Nginx default config is overriding yours

This might occurs when `nginx.conf` also include the default Nginx config and it accidentally override yours, carefully check your `nginx.conf` if it includes any default config path.
E.g: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`, which will also load the nginx default config at the following address
[image]
If this is the case, comment out (or remove) this `include` config statement from your `nginx.conf` file.

#### Verify Nginx configuration

Verify the actual config being applied with command `nginx -T`, this will trigger Nginx to test and print out the configuration, check if the configuration output match your expected result:
[Reference: Nginx commandlines](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/)
You should see something like the following

```
root@22a2e5de75ba:/etc/nginx/conf.d# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        server_name "localhost";
        listen 80;
        location /todo_server/ {
            proxy_pass http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com;
        }
    }
    # 
    
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

#### Problem with Nginx `proxy_pass` configuration

*Similar to the previous answer in this thread*
This will result in unexpected proxy mapping if you specify the trailing slash `/` at the end of the URI.
First, see the completed: [Nginx proxy_pass document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)
I'll use the API `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/` from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)  for demo (it actually serves response for you to test)

**With trailing slash**
The trailing slash at the end indicate that this `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI. In this case, when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

**Example**: with the following config, which is understood as specified with a URI, will resulted in this mapping

```
location /path1/ {
    proxy_pass http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/;  
    # Requesting http://localhost:8080/path1/ will proxy to => http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
    # Requesting http://localhost:8080/path1/1/ will proxy to => http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
}

location /path2/ {
    proxy_pass http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/;
    # Requesting http://localhost:8080/path2/todos/ will proxy to => http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
}
```

**Without trailing slash**
Without the trailing slash `/`, it's understood as no URI scheme, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI.

```
location /todos/ {
    proxy_pass http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com; 
    # Requesting : http://localhost:8080/todos/ will proxy to ==> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
    # Requesting : http://localhost:8080/todos/1 will proxy to ==> http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
}
```

Please also see [the completed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543398/5668956) from @dayo
and also [answer by Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610633/5668956)

Answer (score 4):

Please check that if you have deleted `default.conf` file from `site-enabled` folder.
Run the command if you are in debian based ubuntu system

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to listen on PORT 80, fixed it.

"http" part of nginx config, at: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, is below:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 192.111.111.11:80;
        location /path1/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/path1/
        }
    }
}
```

Now, accessing
    http://192.111.111.11/path1/
will get result of accessing
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/path1/

NOTE:
     Replace the 192.111.111.11 with your IP address in the above.
     Run "ifconfig" command, the "inet addr" part will give your IP address