# How do I rewrite URLs in a proxy response in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm used to using Apache with mod_proxy_html, and am trying to achieve something similar with NGINX.  The specific use case is that I have an admin UI running in Tomcat on port 8080 on a server at the root context:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I need to surface this on port 80, but I have other contexts on the NGINX server running on this host, so want to try and access this at:

```
http://localhost:80/admin/
```

I was hoping that the following super simple server block would do it, but it doesn't quite:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name screenly.local.akana.com;

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the returned content (html) contains URLs to scripts and style info that is all accessed at the root context, so I need to get these URLs rewritten to start with /admin/ instead of /.

How do I do this in NGINX?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

We should first read [the documentation on proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) carefully and fully.

The URI passed to upstream server is determined based on whether "proxy_pass" directive is used with URI or not. Trailing slash in proxy_pass directive means that URI is present and equal to `/`. Absense of trailing slash means hat URI is absent.

**Proxy_pass with URI**:

```
location /some_dir/ {
    proxy_pass http://some_server/;
}
```

With the above, there's the following proxy:

```
http:// your_server/some_dir/ some_subdir/some_file ->
http:// some_server/          some_subdir/some_file
```

Basically, `/some_dir/` gets replaced by `/` to change the request path from `/some_dir/some_subdir/some_file` to `/some_subdir/some_file`.

**Proxy_pass without URI**:

```
location /some_dir/ {
    proxy_pass http://some_server;
}
```

With the second (no trailing slash): the proxy goes like this:

```
http:// your_server /some_dir/some_subdir/some_file ->
http:// some_server /some_dir/some_subdir/some_file
```

Basically, the full original request path gets passed on without changes.

---

So, in your case, it seems you should just drop the trailing slash to get what you want.

---

**Caveat**

Note that automatic rewrite only works if you don't use variables in proxy_pass. If you use variables, you should do rewrite yourself:

```
location /some_dir/ {
  rewrite    /some_dir/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass $upstream_server;
}
```

There are other cases where rewrite wouldn't work, that's why reading documentation is a must.

---

## **Edit**

Reading your question again, it seems I may have missed that you just want to edit the html output.

For that, you can use the [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) directive. Something like ...

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    sub_filter "http://your_server/" "http://your_server/admin/";
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Basically, the string you want to replace and the replacement string

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  I think sub_filter will do it.

Comment: I am curios to what extent nginx is already rewriting the output, woudln't it have to re write the host/hostname in links at a minimum? So eg, wouldn't you `sub_filter "http://localhost/" "http://localhost/admin/"`

Comment: To allow rewriting other than `text/html` mimetype, I had to add also `sub_filter_types *;`.

Comment: Something weird is happening for me with this solution. Resources (*.js, *.css etc are getting fetched), but the page fails to load. i would expect `http://your_server/admin/` to get resolved to `http://your_server` during the proxy_pass but it doesn't and i get an error `react-router /admin/ location did not match any routes` in my application because my application doesn't know anything about '/admin'.

Comment: You may also need to add `proxy_redirect` directive so that the `Location` header sent by the response is also amended in accordance with the url. Check out this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/proxy_redirect-change-replace-location-refresh-response-headers/

Comment: It doesn't look like the first example works as described. Actually `http://your_server/some_dir/some_subdir/some_file` will go to
`http://some_server/`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, the issue was that I'm using variables in `proxy_pass`. In those cases replacement doesn't work.

Answer (score 29):

You may also need the following directive to be set before the first "sub_filter" for backend-servers with data compression:

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

Otherwise it may not work.
For your example it will look like:

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter "http://your_server/" "http://your_server/admin/";
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Comment: BTW: For regex check `subs_filter` (yes, with another `s`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following nginx configuration example:

```
upstream adminhost {
  server adminhostname:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location ~ ^/admin/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://adminhost/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Any problem with the code? Seems like a nice and complex solution to me, solving some caveats of proxying an app that pop up later on. Not sure why `proxy_redirect off;` though. Also I'd add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`.

Comment: > The problem is that the returned content (html) contains URLs to scripts and style info that is all accessed at the root context, so I need to get these URLs rewritten to start with /admin/ instead of /.

At least at the time of posting this comment it doesn't fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no hyperlinks which need to be rewritten with *sub_filter*,
you might just use the `proxy_redirect` directive:

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_redirect / /admin/
}
```

It changes the Location-Header of the response according to the given 'match-rewrite' rule.

Comment: This example of `proxy_redirect` is useless(nginx does this for proxy pass already: it adds no functionality): see the docs at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect