# Rails rewriting link from Blogger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, directory, subdomain, blogger

I use rack-reverse-proxy to setup my Blogger.com to a subdomain of my Ruby on Rails app: pulpoludo.com/blog

It's work, but I have an issue with the link of Blogger which returns to blog.pulpoludo.com (where my Blogger blog is host).

I would like to rewrite this link. But I don't know-how. Can you help me?

(I have found someone who does this in PHP: https://matt-stannard.blogspot.com/2013/02/blogger-in-subdirectory-of-my-domain.html
But I would like to do the same thing with Rails and a gem maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot use rack-reverse-proxy because it does not allow you to change the response (you need to rewrite the page you retrieve using a regular expression replacement, as in the example you link to.

Also, you should probably avoid using rack-reverse-proxy in production, as it will keep your ruby processes busy waiting for the backend responses, that might fail or be slow. And:

> It is not meant for production systems

You should instead proxy from your front HTTP acceptor (nginx or other). For nginx you can see a very thorough response, using a combination of `proxy_pass` and `sub_filter`, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543398/384417.

---

edit: If it's not possible to use nginx or another reverse proxy, you can still do it in ruby.

`rack-reverse-proxy` supports transformers, you can build one yourself, and register it so it's run on the response. This (closed) issue will help, it is exactly what you need: https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy/issues/65. The caveat (as always when changing responses) is that you have to update the `Content-Length` response header to match the updated size of the body.

Comment: I host my app on heroku and I have my domain name on OVH. I never use nginx or apache. It is on Heroku or on my app ?
Sorry I am lost in devop

Comment: Edited to cover your newly found restriction