# How to Reverse Proxy with URL Rewriting and Trailing Slash with NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setup with NGINX and behind my reverse proxy, I have two VPN Servers; one for students and one for admin, which requires UI access for management purposes.

```
Student's VPN UI:  192.168.101.10:443
Admin's VPN UI:    192.168.101.6:443
```

In production, I have only one single DNS name `vpn.internal.example.com` and I am trying to create a reverse proxy based on the specified trailing slash:

```
Incoming Request:
https://vpn.internal.example.com/students/foo/bar -> https://192.168.101.10/foo/bar
https://vpn.internal.example.com/admin/foo/bar    -> https://192.168.101.6/foo/bar
```

Basically, any incoming request should be Proxy_pass without the URI to the internal VPN Server's but when the request is sent back to the user, the trailing slash should be amended.

```
Returning Request:
https://192.168.101.10/foo/bar ->   https://vpn.internal.example.com/student/foo/bar
https://192.168.101.6/foo/bar  ->   https://vpn.internal.example.com/admin/foo/bar
```

I was hoping that this simple configuration would do the trick, I'm only showing a portion of the config for simplicity:

```
upstream vpn-student {
    server 192.168.101.10:443;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...

    server_name vpn.internal.example.com;
    location /student/ {
        proxy_pass https://vpn-student/;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter "https://vpn-student/" "https://vpn-student/student/";
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
}
```

I tried using the `sub_filter` option as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542282/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-in-a-proxy-response-in-nginx). But didn't have much success.

Also, sometimes when I type *vpn.internal.example.com/students/* the web URL reverts back to *vpn.internal.example.com*

Perhaps someone could shed light on How to solve this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: You should use regular expressions in your location block. Create a group for everything after the /student/ and refer to it in the proxy_pass command. I hope i pushed you in the right direction, even tho i didnt give a full solution.

Comment: I tried adding `location ~ ^/student/(.*)$ {` to the location block, as well as something like `proxy_pass https://vpn-student/$1$is_args$args;`. When I type `https://$url/student/login`, the login page shows but when authenticating the server have a general failure, seems that it cannot send/receive the request when /student/ trailing slash is present. If I type `https://$url/student/` then the browser sends me back to `https://$url/`. You did something! But still far off of the end result :/