# NGINX and load balancing with 404 error

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx for reverse proxy and load balancing. 
I can see page jump between myapp.com and google.com, but it only display 404 not found page, not the main page.
The config is below:

upstream backend

```
server myapp.com;
server www.google.com;
```

server

```
listen 80;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Do you guys have any ideasabout the configuration issue?

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but it's certainly worth trying: [nginx proxy\_pass 404 error, don't understand why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157893/nginx-proxy-pass-404-error-dont-understand-why).  ALSO: Consider posting on ServerFault.com - you might have better luck...

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks mate