# Nginx reverse proxy return 404

Tags: nginx

My Nginx installed and running, below is the config from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` , I want to forward all `/api/*` to my tomcat server, which is running on the same server at port 9100(type `http://myhost:9100/api/apps` works) , otherwise, serve static file under '/usr/share/nginx/html'. Now I type `http://myhost/api/apps` give an 404. What's the problem here?

```
upstream  myserver {
    server   localhost:9100 weight=1;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;



    location ^~ /api/ {
       proxy_pass http://myserver/;
    }

    location / {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `proxy_pass` statement may *optionally* modify the URI before passing it upstream. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

In this form:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://myserver/;
}
```

The URI `/api/foo` is passed to `http://myserver/foo`.

By deleting the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://myserver;
}
```

The URI `/api/foo` is now passed to `http://myserver/api/foo`.